# error: The branch 'yourname' is not fully merged with removed remote

Tags: git, github

Can't remove local branch that was merged and removed from GitHub.

```
$ git branch  -d startapp
warning: not deleting branch 'startapp' that is not yet merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/startapp', even though it is merged to HEAD.
error: The branch 'startapp' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D startapp'.

$ git branch
* master
  startapp

$ git checkout startapp
Switched to branch 'startapp'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/startapp' by 65 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

$ git pull
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'startapp'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

The branch was removed after it was merged from GitHub. It is also fully merged in to master.

```
$ git log --graph --left-right --cherry-pick --oneline master...startapp
$
$ git log --graph --left-right --oneline master...startapp
$
```

Why the complain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `man git-branch`:

```
-d, --delete
   Delete a branch. The branch must be fully merged in its upstream
   branch, or in HEAD if no upstream was set with --track or
   --set-upstream.
```

Your branch is not fully merged to the upstream branch that was set (
and now it cannot be so merged because that upstream branch has been
deleted).

This is a reasonable safety check: you want to think twice about deleting a
branch that has commits not pushed to its origin. If you happen to know that 
everything is hunky dory, then follow the advice in the diagnostic:

```
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D startapp'.
```

Comment: The branch is fully merged to upstream master before being merged, and that master is tracked locally - that should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

If the branch is fully merged to master, simply do a checkout to master and then

```
git branch -D <your-fully-merged-branch>
```

Git is somewhat incorrect, as the message you receive is, in fact, a warning, and not an error.

In your specific case, it's normal that when `pull`ing from a merged branch you don't get any `ref`s. Go ahead and run `-D` and there should be no problems.